# Scale Angular PDF Viewer to fit in enclosing elements

Tags: css, angularjs, layout, pdf.js

I'm using the [Angular PDF Viewer](https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer), and it's brilliant, and I love it, but I'm having a terrible time getting it to scale right.

Here's some example code (using [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/), but the question is just as relevant if I were using Bootstrap scaffolding):

```
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-8-24">
    <pdf-viewer delegate-handle="loaded_doc_viewer" url="uploaded_doc_data_url" scale="1"></pdf-viewer>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The problem is that the size of the pdf-viewer is dependent on the size of the pdf and not on the containing grid element.

Is there a way to size the canvas without doing something silly and hacky, ideally using percentages for width (ala `width:100%`) to keep it in line with the grid?  If not, is there a silly and hacky way to accomplish the same thing?